# Aggregate values and time using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have the following JSON result from API .

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value" : "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 00:00:00"

    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value": "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 00:15:00"

    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value": "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 00:30:00"
    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "ResultValue": "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 00:45:00"
    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value": "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 01:00:00"

    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value": "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 01:15:00"

    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value": "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 01:30:00"
    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value": "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 01:45:00"
    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value": "0",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 02:00:00"
    }
]
```

I am trying to de-serialize and write to list and then aggregating the values

```
 var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestData>>(JSONResult).ToList();
 var aggList = items.GroupBy(u=> new { u.ID,u.TimeStamp}).Select(g => new TestData { ID = g.Key.ID,TimeStamp = g.Key.TimeStamp ,TotalValue = g.Sum(k =>K.Value)}).ToList();
```

How can i change the LINQ query to show the result like mentioned below.

```
Id : 1
 TotalValue : 40
 TimeStamp : 2019-10-21 01:00:00

 Id : 1
 TotalValue : 40
 TimeStamp : 2019-10-21 02:00:00
```

Comment: Why does one of the elements have an ID of ResultValue instead of Value?

Comment: Group by TimeStamp's date part only and TimeStamp's hour ... it would be obvious if you write on the paper in english what you wana achive

Comment: Is `items.GroupBy` just a typo in your posted code? Shouldn't it be `testList`?

Comment: Before the GroupBy use OrderBy date.  It doesn't look like you need to Group by the date.

Comment: @Selvin thanks for the suggestion. Let me try grouping by timestamps date and hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` Date and Hour together:

```
var aggList = items.GroupBy(u => new { u.ID, u.TimeStamp.Date, u.TimeStamp.Hour })
                            .Select(g => new TestData
                            {
                                ID = g.Key.ID,
                                TimeStamp = g.Key.Date.AddHours(g.Key.Hour),
                                Value = g.Sum(k => k.Value)
                            }).ToList();
```

It will give you following result:

```
ID : 1
TotalValue : 30
TimeStamp : 21.10.2019 00:00:00

ID : 1
TotalValue : 40
TimeStamp : 21.10.2019 01:00:00

ID : 1
TotalValue : 0
TimeStamp : 21.10.2019 02:00:00
```

Comment: how do i change query if i have aggregate values starting from 15 minutes instead of 00:00

Comment: Aggregate these values as first hour  {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value": "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 00:15:00"

    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value": "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 00:30:00"
    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "ResultValue": "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 00:45:00"
    },
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Value": "10",
        "TimeStamp": "2019-10-21 01:00:00"

    }